# What are these "holes" in the F-104 for?

Tags: feature-identification, f-104

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oax-YsLh6CE) there are two "holes" that I'm curious about.

One is rectangular in the all white section of the plane that flutters open/close during flight. The other is somewhat oval and is on the line between the blue and white areas.

[image]

It appears to slowly close with none of the "flutter" displayed by the other.

Comment: The second "hole" I am referring to is just forward of the first one, above the wing.  It is visible, for example, at 7 seconds.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I found [online](https://ww2aircraft.net/forum/threads/f-104-parts-manual-1100-pagess.24887/) the maintenance manual

From part 1, page 2-233 (270 of the pdf) we find that the "holes" are the Engine Ground Cooling Doors:

[image: F-104 Engine Ground Cooling Doors Figure]

Note: the nose of the aircraft is on the left in this diagram.

Furthermore, form this cutaway:

[image: F-104 Cutaway]

we see that the oil coolers (40 in the diagram) are behind the rectangular "hole"

Comment: Nice find, also mentioned in the [F-104D flight manual](https://www.starfighters.it/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/Flight-Manual-F-104D-USAF-Series-Aircraft-1960.pdf#page=17): *cooling air for engine ground operations is supplied through four single and four double inboard opening suck-in doors (spring loaded to closed) just aft of the firewall*. It seems these doors were first added for the [1958 altitude record](https://vintageaviationnews.com/warbird-articles/into-the-thin-air-f-104-starfighter-world-altitude-records.html).